# TypeError: Player() takes no arguments

Tags: python, typeerror, tic-tac-toe

I tried to programm a tic tac toe game with python but i but I always get the error Player() takes no argument i don t know how to fix it

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    player_a = Player(1)
    player_b = Player(-1)
    board = Board()
    active_player = player_a
    while not board.is_full():
        board.print_board()
        try:
            cell = int(input("Where do you want to place your sign? [1-9]"))
        except ValueError:
            continue
        cell = cell -1
        if cell < 0 or cell > 8:
            print("please enter a number between 1and 9")
            continue
        if not board.make_turn(cell, active_player):
            print("Invalid Move")
            continue
```

Comment: Hello, can you show the class Player ?

Answer (score 0):

In your `Player` class, in the `__init__` function you need to add an argument.

```
class Player:
    def __init__(self, index):
        self.index = index
```